# How is the following integral rigorously meant to be understood?

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the following integral on the unit three sphere 
$$
\int_{S^3}\frac{1}{x^2}\,d^3x
$$

where $x^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$. I have quite some working knowledge on integrals but I have big gaps on the foundations. I want to know how the integral above is supposed to be understood in a rigorous way. The problem I see is that

$$
\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
is not well defined in our integration region. Nonetheless if we naively go to spherical coordinates the jacobian kills the source of our problems

$$
d^3=x^2dx\sin\theta{}\,d\theta{}\,d\phi
$$
and threfore

$$
\int_{S^3}\frac{1}{x^2}\,d^3x=\int_0^1dx\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta{}\,d\theta{}\,\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=4\pi
$$
Is the argument above rigorous? can I perform Riemann integrals of not well defined functions?

Comment: Well, you may just compute the integral over $S^2\cap\{|x|>\varepsilon\}$ and let $\varepsilon\to 0$. It is just an improper Riemann integral.

Answer (score 1):

This is analogous to an improper integral in one dimension. You can view the integral in many ways, for example
$$\int_{S^3}\frac1{x^2}\,d^3x=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{\{x\in S^3\colon|x|>\varepsilon\}}\frac1{x^2}\,d^3x.$$
Since the integrand is positive, there are many ways to do the limit procedure.
For example, replace the integrand by $\min(1/x^2,M)$ and then let $M\to\infty$.
(The technical result that says it doesn't matter much how you perform the limit, is known as the monotone convergence theorem).

If the integrand changes sign, you need to start worrying about the integral equivalent of conditionally convergent series.